# W in the brightness distribution

Tags: interferometry

What is W in the brightness (intensity) distribution, please?
Alpha is the position of the star; lambda, the wavelength; t, the time; P, the polarization.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you can tell us where you found this, and perhaps provide some more context, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Context is essential... there are some rough conventions of which symbols are used for which physical properties - but that is anything but a given. That is more true the less common a formula is. And this is not even a formula, but just a function call, so that no-one can even draw conclusions from the formula.

Comment: It was in a lecture about interferometry that in this all astrophysicists are interested. However, then it was talked just about the other variables as I described above.